# MongoDB. Cast object-value to array of values if another object added

Tags: mongodb

I am very newbie with MongoDB. Suppose I have a document with a simple key-value pair:

```
{foo:"bar"}
```

Now I want to add a new value to this very key, so it will look like this:

```
{foo:["bar", "second-bar"]}
```

Is there any way how can I do this in Mongo without retrieving original value from database, wrapping both values into array and saving it back?

Comment: No, you need to change the document structure and make "foo" an array field.